# Html Css how positioning playing cards correctly on page?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a memory card game and the cards don't seem to be displaying  on the page correctly. like this: [image of end result][1]. I am using css to simply place 4 playing cards on the page: 2 cards top and bottom, but can't seem to find what I have done wrong and the footer is not displaying underneath the cards. Any help would be appreciated...

Here is my code with instructions: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ray1234/zeqks3kq/2/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Memory Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" >
</head>
<body>

<nav class="clearfix">
    <a href="#">instructions</a>
    <a href="#">games</a>
</nav>

<h1>Memory Game</h1>
<h2>Instructions</h2>



<h3>My game is fun to play, you will want to play it again and again. My game is fun because it's easy to play. This game is awesome because of how its built.</h3>

<p>Concentration, also known as Match Match, Memory, Pelmanism, Shinkei-suijaku, Pexeso or simply Pairs, is a card game in which all of the cards are laid face down on a surface and two cards are flipped face up over each turn. The object of the game is to turn over pairs of matching cards.</p>

<hr>

<div class="board">
    <div class="card">adf</div>
    <div class="card">af</div>
    <div class="card">adsf</div>
    <div class="card">asdf</div>
</div>

<footer>
    <p>Created with <img src="images/heart.png" width="10px"> by <span class="name">razor</span></p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
h1 {
    color: rgb(2, 132, 130);
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    color: #ffd700;
    text-align: center;
}

h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    text-align: center;
}

.board {
    height: 80%;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 3px solid black;
    float: left;
    margin: 8%;

}


.card {
    height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float: left;
}


.name {
    color: #ff0000;
}

nav {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #808080;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:  #ffbf00;
    color: white;
    padding: 35px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

a:hover {
    background-color:  #ee5f3c;
}


.clearfix:after {
        visibility: hidden;
        display: block;
        content: " ";
        clear: both;
        height: 0;
        font-size: 0;
      }
 footer {
    text-align: center;
 }
```

Comment: Just fyi, you didn't include the image link

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using cards I would recommend you use the flexbox which is compatible on [most browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) it will handle the layout of your cards on the page, you can find some simple flexbox tutorials on the net, i would reccomend this one https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

This should not impact your footer and allow you to position the rest of the elements more easily.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float of the footer and add clear:both to it instead.

```
 footer {
    text-align: center;
  clear:both;
 }
```

That will make sure the footer stays below the cards.

Comment: here is the image link: http://fundamentals.generalassemb.ly/assets/elkwebdesign/memorygame6.png

Comment: here is the image link to what it should look like: http://fundamentals.generalassemb.ly/assets/elkwebdesign/memorygame6.png

Comment: thanks will give that a try. Here is the updated version of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/ray1234/zeqks3kq/27/